# Ways to create fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently creating fragments by making a different class for each of them. Now I'm only testing with 7 fragments and this is taking way too much memory and space already when using the application. For my pageviewer-supported application I need like 400-500 fragments, where you can slide thru them horizontally. All the fragments will have the same background, same buttons but only different text on them. So I was thinking there's no need to create a class for every of them as they are actually kind of the same. Conclusion : Is there any aother way to create fragments instead of making a class for each of them?

Here's my code (to be able to observe the way that I'm currently managing fragments) :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }        
    });

}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {Fragment f = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
    {
    f = new DummySectionFragment();//YourFragment
    // set arguments here, if required
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    f.setArguments(args);
    break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        f = new Fragment2();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        f = new Fragment3();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        f = new Fragment4();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        f = new Fragment5();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        f = new Fragment6();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        f = new Fragment7();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }

    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
    }


    return f;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 7;
    }


}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }


}  public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}  public static class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment3() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}  public static class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment4() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment4, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}  public static class Fragment5 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment5() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment5, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    } }  
    public static class Fragment6 extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public Fragment6() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment6, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }   } 
        public static class Fragment7 extends Fragment {
            /**
             * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
             * fragment.
             */
            public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            public Fragment7() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment7, container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes create only one fragment class and pass the argument while returning the fragment from your viewpageradapter, and in your fragment display text according to the argument you have passed

Comment: Okay, so I got a little confuse. Basically I create only one fragment, the fragment class, and this fragment will repeat as many times as the argument is set to, and depending on the argument's number, I'll give a text for the fragment? Is that right?

Comment: every time you will create a new instance of that fragment with different arguments

Comment: In getItem method of your pageradapter return only that fragment, do not use switch case there

Comment: Uhmm, I'm still kind of confused about the text part, giving different text to each argument. Can you please give me an code example?